# View Elements autoresizing is not working in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, autoresizingmask

I'm having a viewController(say,SecondViewController) in which in xib file i have added a view(say,containerView) and to that containerView i'm adding another view controllers view as a subView

```
[containerView addSubView:abcViewController.view];
```

& autoresizing mask is set for all views,If i'm running my code in portrait mode,entering SecondViewController & then if i change orientations autoresizing is working fine.If i enter to SecondViewController by Landscape mode then autoresizing is not at all working.
How to overcome this problem.

Comment: Where are you setting autoresize property of secondViewController ?

Comment: @franknirania in secondViewController .xib file.

Comment: having the same problem, do you solve that

Comment: @justicepenny still facing same problem,actually now after launching my app if i enter my SecondViewController from protrait mode & then if i change orientation autoresizing is working fine but as soon as i launch my app & if i enter to SecondViewController in landscape mode then the height of my SecondViewController.view is not changing  (same portrait height it is taking),width is reflecting correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please check **Attributes Inspector** for your *SecondViewController* in Interface Builder.
It has a layout attribute called **Resize View From NIB** which allows or prevents the view controller to be presented, to be resized to fit in presenting view controller at loading, or keep the form at designed in Interface Builder.

[image]